# Generalisation of function in Golang

Tags: sql, function, go, generalization

I want to write a generic function which handles SQL queries.

[Sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx) module provides function `StructScan()`, which automatically scans results into struct fields.

```
type Place struct {
    Country       string
    City          sql.NullString
    TelephoneCode int `db:"telcode"`
}

rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM place")
for rows.Next() {
    var p Place
    err = rows.StructScan(&p)
}
```

So, proposed function signature looks as:

```
func Query(db *sql.DB, query) {
    rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * FROM place")
    for rows.Next() {
        var p CustomType
        err = rows.StructScan(&p)
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know in advance the exact type of the variable denoted as Custom Type since it differs depending on a particular query (some queries returns **string**, another **int** etc).

One of the options would be to pass **type** `CustomType` as argument to `Query`. However, I do not know how to initialise the local variable `p` with needed type.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: To answer your general question: That's not idiomatic Go. Instead, find a way to pass in the receiver, rather than creating it dynamically. The latter is practically impossible, and far harder to use anyway.

Comment: But to answer your specific use case, why not just use [sqlx.Get](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Get)?

Comment: There is no way you can create a dynamic struct with required type coming from the database. If you want to store the value dynamically use interface.

Comment: "I want to write a generic function" translated either to "I'm experienced in runtime reflection and willing to pay the runtime costs" or to "I'll fail miserably trying to do so." Consider redesigning.

Comment: Hint: json.Unmarshal does something very similar to what you want to do here. Pass the destination as `interface{}`.

Comment: [sqlx.Get](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Get) as stated by @Flimzy is actually doing the same wrapping the result to an `interface{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your general question: That's not idiomatic Go. Instead, find a way to pass in the receiver, rather than creating it dynamically. The latter is practically impossible, and far harder to use anyway.

To answer your specific use case, just use either sqlx's [DB.Get](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Get) or [DB.Select](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Select), which accomplish exactly the same thing as your proposed wrapper function, but in a Go-idiomatic way.